# ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6 Add View/Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a Web Project with VS2015's template for ASP.NET5. I have also disabled the Authentication. Now I was wondering, why I wasn't able to have a view being created automatically by VS. So I found out, that adding "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc" to the project.json's dependency list with the appropriate version number did the trick to at least be able to add an auto-generated view for a specific Model and DataContext by right-clicking the "Views"-Folder.

But I couldn't get it working to be able to do it also by right-clicking a "return View(someViewModel)" as it is possible to do with ASP.NET 4.6.1 for example. I already did a lot of research as it was always a handy function to create a view that easy.

**EDIT:**
I found, that by going to Tools -> Customize -> Commands, selecting Context menu and then "Editor Context Menus | Code Window" from the dropdown, that there is th Add View option, I just don't get it now, how to enable it when being in a controller for example

Comment: I can't do it either in my projects, I never looked into it but I don't think it is implemented yet for ASP.Net 5. Hope you find an answer as I would like this ability as well.

Comment: Well I think it's more just something with the mapping of Options, as I got it for ASP.NET 4.6.1 projects AND for ASP.NET 5 projects. So the option/ability is already there, it's just lacking in the context menu

Comment: When I use VS 2015 for .Net 1-4.6 projects I can right click on the view name in the controller and create a new view, but in .Net 5 projects I can't.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I am trying to say, and i can't get it working, nither with the customization tab

Comment: So instead of creating an Empty ASP.NET 5 project, why not chose the Web Application template and select No Authentication. This will give you a template with a bunch of stuff to which you’ll have the ability to remove the stuff you don’t care for.

Comment: @Vlince the second sentence already says, that I used a web poject with no authentication

Comment: Oh my bad! My guess is that the Add-View is available since you might create a View strongly typed amongst other things (like choosing the Layout and whatnot) but I don’t think we will have the Add-Controller since in MVC 6 both WebAPI and MVC Controllers are unified hence no need to select a particular type of controller. Unless you want the scaffolding stuff then that may come later.

Comment: @Vlince Well, but by adding that dependency I'm also able to add a controller directly by right-klicking onto the "Controllers"-Folder